# Error with virtual env on python (MAC)

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I have a problem working with virtualenv on a MAC...this is what I do:

```
Tester-MacBook-Pro:myproject tester$ virtualenv foobar
New python executable in /Users/tester/Documents/myproject/foobar/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /Users/tester/...ct/foobar/bin/python - setuptools pip wheel:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/Users/tester/anaconda/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
    import io as _io
  File "/Users/tester/anaconda/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/tester/Documents/myproject/foobar/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder
  Referenced from: /Users/tester/Documents/myproject/foobar/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/tester/Documents/myproject/foobar/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tester/anaconda/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/tester/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/Users/tester/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 945, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/Users/tester/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 901, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/Users/tester/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 797, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/tester/...ct/foobar/bin/python - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

Comment: root cause is `ImportError: dlopen(/Users/tester/Documents/myproject/foobar/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder`. Good luck with that. Are you stuck with 2.7? or could you try more recent versions like 3.5?

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same problem.

It turns out I was using python-2.7.13 and downgrading to 2.7.10 solved that issue.

If you are using Anaconda, you can do that by running:
`$ conda install python=2.7.10`